# E-mail text being truncated when moved to webpage from database?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a table that I populate using PHP which pulls from a SQL Server database.  Right now, only the first few hundred characters are pulled from the SQL Server table cells so the displayed e-mails are shown as cut off.

What is causing the rest of the characters to be truncated when I move the data?

Example of two messages being cut off:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the full e-mail text is coming from the database?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Good point, I did a debug with substr and it looks like I am only pulling the first few hundred characters from the database

Comment: My guess is that your database column is set to `VARCHAR`. Try changing it to `TEXT`

Comment: @Ares Looks like that was the problem.  Feel free to put this down as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your column is set to a type (`VARCHAR`?) that cannot hold that much data. If you are storing long strings from user input you may want to try changing your column to some other type such as `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT` depending on how much text you are expecting.